# android 7.1.2 + ARMv7

Tags: android, build, android-source, flex-lexer

I met this problem when I was compiling the Android 7.1.2 source code after I updated my debian. I do not know what is the real problem .
It seems problem from the flex. However, how can i solve it?

> FAILED: /bin/bash -c "prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex/flex-2.5.39
> -oout/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaidl-common_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp
> system/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.ll" flex-2.5.39: loadlocale.c:130:
> _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed
> .
> Aborted

Comment: What is the value of `LC_TIME` in your shell? (`locale | grep TIME` will show you.) Will it work if you `export LC_ALL=C` first?

Comment: By the way, this is not a flex issue as such. It's a problem encountered by glibc when `setlocale` is called (probably).

Comment: @penf: great that you got it to work but the locale problem is a distro bug, assuming the locale is part of your distro, and should probably be reported (unless it already has been, of course).

Comment: same in my ubuntu 22

Answer (score 55):

Same issue for me on Ubuntu 18.04. LC_TIME was set to en_GB.UTF-8.

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Fixed it for me

Comment: i was also facing the same error and before make i run "export LC_ALL=C" in terminal and Issue is fixed. How to integrate this variable in android source code so that i can avoid to run before compilation .

Answer (score 4):

I built AOSP (Android O/P) downloaded from Google on a newly setup 18.04 and it built fine. Did not have to change the locale. 
Locale was set to en_GB.UTF-8.

Then I had to build Android N, an IMX distro, on the same machine and the build failed with the above error. After changing the locale variable the build worked fine.

Comment: I have same issue in ubuntu22 and android7-sourcecode

Answer (score 4):

I had this again recently building `AOSP` with `Ubuntu 22.04`. Setting the `locale` didn't work at all.

However i found this [github thread](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/bug_tracker/issues/136) which suggested to rebuild flex with

```
cd prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex
rm flex-2.5.39
tar zxf flex-2.5.39.tar.gz
cd flex-2.5.39
./configure
make
mv flex ../
cd ../
rm -rf flex-2.5.39
mv flex flex-2.5.39
```

which solved the error for me.

Comment: Thank you so much @Flo . This fixed my issue as well on ubuntu22.04 host, ubuntu22.04 docker container to build AOSP. I just can't understand why bundled flex in prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex is causing this problem ...

Answer (score 1):

i was also facing the same error and before make i run "export LC_ALL=C" in terminal and Issue is fixed.
How to integrate this variable in android source code so that i can avoid to run before compilation .